# displaying events doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display events from a MySQL database in a full calendar.
Here is my code, json-events.php:

```
   @mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)
    or die("Impossible de se connecter ! Vérifier le nom du serveur, le login ou le mot de passe !");

@mysql_select_db("$bdd")
    or die ("Impossible de trouver la base de données !");  



$req_lire ="SELECT idfiches,titrefiches,DATE_FORMAT(fiches.rvfiches, '%Y-%m-%d') as startdate FROM fiches"; 

    $lire2 = mysql_query($req_lire) or die($req_lire."<br>\n".mysql_error());

 $events = array();
    while ($reponse = mysql_fetch_array($lire2))
{
$id = $reponse['idfiches'];
$title = $reponse['titrefiches'];
$start = $reponse['startdate'];

$events = array(
            'id' => "$id",
            'title' => "$title",
            'start' => "$start"
            );
}
echo json_encode($events);
```

Nothing is displayed and no error.
When I try my request in a sole file, it's ok.
Could you help me?

Comment: I believe you want to accumulate into `$events` via `$events[] = array(...);` note the `[]`.  `json_encode()` will return NULL on failure, so `var_dump($events)` to verify its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're replacing your $events array with whatever you got in the last iteration.

Try to update this:

```
$events = array(
        'id' => "$id",
        'title' => "$title",
        'start' => "$start"
        );
```

into this:

```
$events[] = array(
        'id' => "$id",
        'title' => "$title",
        'start' => "$start"
        );
```

That way, you'll be appending each iteration's data onto your $events array.

Comment: Hello!  Actually, the array give me the good results (I asked directly json-events.php

Comment: The problem is that fullCalendar expects an array of JSON objects, and you're just sending a single object - I already tried - so just add the extra brackets and it should work. `$events` to `$events[]`

Comment: Hello!  I did it.  here is my code >> while ($reponse = mysql_fetch_array($lire2))
{
$id = $reponse['idfiches'];
$title = $reponse['titrefiches'];
$start = $reponse['startdate'];

$events [] = array(
   'id' => "$id",
   'title' => "$title",
   'start' => "$start"
   );
}



echo json_encode($events);  But it's not even good

Comment: It works in my test environment with only the change I mentioned above: http://sandbox.andrux.net/full-calendar.php

Comment: I see...  Well, I don't understand what's happening...  could it be due to my wamp server (2.2)? I don't know where in my code the problem could be.Because all is ok in weekly and daily part, just the monthly one is disturbed... Could I give you the whole code from jason.html and json-events.php ?Could it be in a .js file, the problem is ?Thnak you very much for your help, I'd like to understand.

Comment: sure, let me take a look at them